# Basic loop question, trying to add new column with value changes

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I am trying to see when the location changes in a row, the three possible locations are: Lower, Misc and Upper. Each column represents a month, so there can be more than one detection as seen below in column f. So for the below example, a location change would have occurred in column d, f and h. I am trying to paste these changes in a new column at the end of the row.
This is the code I tried, however the loop is not working. The reason I gsub'd the locations for numbers is because the loop seemed to be having problems with the words, so I thought numbers might make it work, however it still does not.

```
df= read.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Mote/TempMovement/test-row.csv")
df

tag  a    b  c  d    e     f       g     h

228 Lower 0 0 Upper 0 Upper,Misc Misc Lower

df$a<-as.character(df$a)
df$b<-as.character(df$b)
df$c<-as.character(df$c)
df$d<-as.character(df$d)
df$e<-as.character(df$e)
df$f<-as.character(df$f)
df$g<-as.character(df$g)
df$h<-as.character(df$h)

df<-gsub("Lower", "1",df)
df<-gsub("Misc", "2", df)
df<-gsub("Upper", "3", df)

for (j in (df)){
if (j+1 == j || "0") {
next
} else {
df$move<-paste(j+1)
}

}
```

My desired outcome is:

```
tag  a    b  c  d    e     f       g     h    move

228 Lower 0  0 Upper 0 Upper,Misc Misc Lower  d,f,h
```

Comment: A. why all the "as.character" lines? (consider adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `read.csv` call). B. Can you show what your desired output looks like?

Comment: @iod I am pretty new to r, I was just trying to make sure the values were seen as characters because before I did that, all of the Lower, Misc and Upper became 1s when I tried to gsub anything.

Comment: @iod I added my desired outcome to the original question because the format didnt come out properly in these comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tidyverse` (which assumes there is more than one row - it could be simpler if there is actually only the one row; also assumes tags are unique for each row):

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
df= read.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Mote/TempMovement/test-row.csv", 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # avoid the need for as.character
left_join(df,
      df %>% gather("var","val",-1) %>% # create a helper dataframe in a "long" format
          filter(val!=0) %>% # take out the cases with 0
          separate_rows(val) %>% # break apart observations with more than one action
          group_by(tag) %>%
          summarize(move=paste(var[val!=lag(val) & !is.na(lag(val))],collapse=",")), #create a data.frame of all the "move" column
      by="tag") # merge the move column into the original dataframe
```

Result:

```
  tag     a b c     d e          f    g     h  move
1 228 Lower 0 0 Upper 0 Upper,Misc Misc Lower d,f,h
```

If you're not familiar with `gather`, try seeing the result for just `df %>% gather("var","val",-1)`

Comment: Youre amazing, thank you so much, you dont know how long ive been working on this problem!! Just tried it with additional rows and it worked as well!

Comment: One additional question, sorry, I applied it to my massive real data set and got "Evaluation error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'." Any idea what this means?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the data structure. May be something to do with how it interpreted the file when creating the data.frame. Can you share the `str(df)`?

Comment: It came out really long, heres a sample of one column if that helps. $ 2018-09-01 :List of 263
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0 
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : chr "Lower"
  ..$ : chr "Misc"
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : num 0
  .. [list output truncated]

Comment: You have 263 columns in the full dataset?

Comment: Here is the first few columns of summary: All of the follow are like column 2017-05-01. Region.Init is to be included in the analysis, the reason it looks different is because there are no zeros. Hope this is readable....Tag_ID (Length:263,  Class :character, Mode  :character)    Region.Init (Length:263, Class :character, Mode  :character)     2017-05-01. (Length: 1, 1,1 ,1 etc, Class: -none-, -none-, -none-, etc., Class: numeric, numeric, character, etc.)

Comment: I don't suppose you can share the actual file? It's hard to figure things out this way

Comment: Or you can try out the solution step by step and see where you encounter the error

Comment: It looks from your str like df is a list, not a dataframe. Any idea why?

Comment: I just did class() of my df and it said its a dataframe. How would I could about sharing the file with you?

Comment: I figured out that columns 3:end were classified as list. I was able to fix it using many lines of:     MARK.monthly$`2019-01-01` <- vapply(MARK.monthly$`2019-01-01`, paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L)). However, I am curious if there is an easier/more robust way of doing this so that I dont have to have 19 lines of this code? Thanks

Comment: The question is why they were read in as a list in the first place. Hard to tell without seeing the original file. Also, can't you just do `MARK.monthly[,3:ncols(MARK.monthly)] <- vapply(MARK.monthly[,3:ncols(MARK.monthly)], paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L))`?